# Получить уникальные значения по каждому столбцу DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Красивый вариант получения уникальных значений по каждому столбцу `DataFrame`.

DataFrame: https://yadi.sk/i/CiNCLc2juUxaXw

Мой вариант решения:

```
adult_train_drop = adult_train.drop(['Age', 'fnlwgt', 'Education_Num', 'Capital_Gain', 'Capital_Loss', 'Hours_per_week'], axis=1)
for col in adult_train_drop:
    print(col, ': ', adult_train[col].unique())
    print()
```

Результат:

```
Workclass :  [' State-gov' ' Self-emp-not-inc' ' Private' ' Federal-gov' ' Local-gov'
 nan ' Self-emp-inc' ' Without-pay' ' Never-worked']

Education :  [' Bachelors' ' HS-grad' ' 11th' ' Masters' ' 9th' ' Some-college'
 ' Assoc-acdm' ' Assoc-voc' ' 7th-8th' ' Doctorate' ' Prof-school'
 ' 5th-6th' ' 10th' ' 1st-4th' ' Preschool' ' 12th']

Martial_Status :  [' Never-married' ' Married-civ-spouse' ' Divorced'
 ' Married-spouse-absent' ' Separated' ' Married-AF-spouse' ' Widowed']

Occupation :  [' Adm-clerical' ' Exec-managerial' ' Handlers-cleaners' ' Prof-specialty'
 ' Other-service' ' Sales' ' Craft-repair' ' Transport-moving'
 ' Farming-fishing' ' Machine-op-inspct' ' Tech-support' nan
 ' Protective-serv' ' Armed-Forces' ' Priv-house-serv']

Relationship :  [' Not-in-family' ' Husband' ' Wife' ' Own-child' ' Unmarried'
 ' Other-relative']

Race :  [' White' ' Black' ' Asian-Pac-Islander' ' Amer-Indian-Eskimo' ' Other']

Sex :  [' Male' ' Female']

Country :  [' United-States' ' Cuba' ' Jamaica' ' India' nan ' Mexico' ' South'
 ' Puerto-Rico' ' Honduras' ' England' ' Canada' ' Germany' ' Iran'
 ' Philippines' ' Italy' ' Poland' ' Columbia' ' Cambodia' ' Thailand'
 ' Ecuador' ' Laos' ' Taiwan' ' Haiti' ' Portugal' ' Dominican-Republic'
 ' El-Salvador' ' France' ' Guatemala' ' China' ' Japan' ' Yugoslavia'
 ' Peru' ' Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc)' ' Scotland' ' Trinadad&Tobago'
 ' Greece' ' Nicaragua' ' Vietnam' ' Hong' ' Ireland' ' Hungary'
 ' Holand-Netherlands']

Target :  [' <=50K' ' >50K']
```

Есть возможность получить подобный результат, но

1. чтобы сам код был компактней (в одну строчку);
2. ответ тоже хотелось бы посимпатичнее, что-то тоже на `DataFrame` похожее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл совсем короткий и логичный вариант:

```
pd.DataFrame(adult_train_drop.apply(pd.unique)).rename(columns={0:'Unique values'})
```

Вывод:

```
                Unique values
Workclass       [ State-gov, Self-emp-not-inc, Private, Fed...
Education       [ Bachelors, HS-grad, 11th, Masters, 9th, ...
Martial_Status  [ Never-married, Married-civ-spouse, Divorce...
Occupation      [ Adm-clerical, Exec-managerial, Handlers-cl...
Relationship    [ Not-in-family, Husband, Wife, Own-child, ...
Race            [ White, Black, Asian-Pac-Islander, Amer-In...
Sex             [ Male, Female]
Country         [ United-States, Cuba, Jamaica, India, nan,...
Target          [ <=50K, >50K]
```

Comment: У меня выдаёт ошибку: arrays must all be same length

Comment: Попробуйте сначала внутренность отдельно посчитать `adult_train_drop.apply(pd.unique)`, если ругается именно она, то попробуйте задать в ней параметр `axis=0` или `axis=1`, а если это уже `pd.DataFrame` ругается, то покажите, что внутренняя штука эта у вас генерит

Comment: Да, всё именно так. Спасибо.